# Ember-cli disable minification on select files

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, minify

Is there anyway I can go about disabling minification on select css/js files? Here's my ember-cli-build.js code:

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    sourcemaps: {
      enabled: true,
      extensions: ['js', 'bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js', 'bower_components/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js', '**/*.min.js', '**/*.min.css', '**/*.woff', '**/*.ttf']
    },
    // import all the assets (technically you could be more precise in picking just the plugins and themes that you require, but for brevity's sake this will work)

  });
  // import the main file
  app.import('bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js', {destDir: 'assets/tinymce'});

  // import the jquery integration file
  app.import('bower_components/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js', {destDir: 'assets/tinymce'});

  // import all the assets (technically you could be more precise in picking just the plugins and themes that you require, but for brevity's sake this will work)
  var tinymceAssets = pickFiles('bower_components/tinymce/', {
    srcDir: '/',
    files: ['**/*.min.js', '**/*.min.css', '**/*.woff', '**/*.ttf'],
    destDir: '/tinymce',
  });
  // Use `app.import` to add additional libraries to the generated
  // output files.
  //
  // If you need to use different assets in different
  // environments, specify an object as the first parameter. That
  // object's keys should be the environment name and the values
  // should be the asset to use in that environment.
  //
  // If the library that you are including contains AMD or ES6
  // modules that you would like to import into your application
  // please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
  // along with the exports of each module as its value.

  // app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
  // app.import('vendor/css/app.css');
  // app.import('vendor/js/jquery.markitup.js');
  // app.import('vendor/js/custom.js');
  app.import('bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js');
  app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');
  return app.toTree([tinymceAssets]);
};
```

Anything having to do with TinyMCE I need uglified...the rest needs to be minified... Does anyone have a solution? Otherwise, I will have extremely long build times and I really can't have that... Thanks!